# I want to categorise entries in a dataframe, e.g. 1970, 1971, 1972 turn into "70s"

Tags: r, apply, categories

That's what I have:

```
   numbers any_data year period
         1       ab 1974   <NA
         2       cd 1975   <NA
         3       ef 1985   <NA
         4       gh 1960   <NA
         5       ij 1955   <NA
```

...and that is what I want:

```
   numbers any_data year period
         1       ab 1974   "70s"
         2       cd 1975   "70s"
         3       ef 1985   "80s"
         4       gh 1960   "older"
         5       ij 1955   "older"
```

I could use a for-loop checking every single entry in the year-column, but there should be a smarter and faster way using apply or similar functions. Unfortunately, I can't figure that out.

```
n <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
a <- c("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij")
y <- c(1974, 1975, 1985, 1960, 1955)
df <- data.frame(numbers = n, any_data = a, year = y, period = NA)

df$period <- factor(df$period, levels =c("70s", "80s", "older"))

for (i in 1:length(df$year)){
  if((df$year[i]  1969) && (df$year[i] < 1980)){
    df$period[i] <- "70s"
  }
  # and so on
}

df
```

That's slow and ugly. Any better ideas?

Comment: Read `help("cut")`.

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

a good, readable and general way would be to use dplyr's `?case_when`.

```
df$period <- 
(df$y %% 100) %>% {dplyr::case_when( . >= 80 ~ "80s",
                                     . >= 70 ~ "70s",
                                     TRUE    ~ "older")}

# [1] "70s"   "70s"   "80s"   "older" "older"
```

another way using `?ifelse`:

```
dec <- as.integer(substr(y, 3 ,3 ))

df$period <-
ifelse(dec > 6, paste0(dec, "0s"), "older")

# [1] "70s"   "70s"   "80s"   "older" "older"
```

or `?cut` as Roland suggests:

```
df$period <-
cut((df$y %% 100), breaks=c(-Inf, 70, 80, Inf), labels = c("older", "70s", "80s"), right = FALSE)

#[1] 70s   70s   80s   older older
#Levels: older 70s 80s
```